# Icinga Mysql migration error Table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, sql, migration, icinga2, icinga

I have tried to perform update for icinga into 2.9.1 and to do this I need to apply migration on a sql database.

The migration uses the following sql query:

2.9.0 migration

```
CREATE TABLE `icingaweb_rememberme`(
    ->   id                int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   username          varchar(254) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   passphrase        varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    ->   random_iv         varchar(24) NOT NULL,
    ->   http_user_agent   text NOT NULL,
    ->   expires_at        timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   ctime             timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   mtime             timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

2.9.1 migration

```
ALTER TABLE `icingaweb_rememberme`
    ->     MODIFY random_iv varchar(32)  NOT NULL;
```

**The issue** is that when I try to perfom it I get confilicting error messages

**Full migration log**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> use icingaweb2
Database changed
MariaDB [icingaweb2]> CREATE TABLE `icingaweb_rememberme`(
    ->   id                int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   username          varchar(254) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   passphrase        varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    ->   random_iv         varchar(24) NOT NULL,
    ->   http_user_agent   text NOT NULL,
    ->   expires_at        timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   ctime             timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   mtime             timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'icingaweb_rememberme' already exists
MariaDB [icingaweb2]> ALTER TABLE `icingaweb_rememberme`
    ->     MODIFY random_iv varchar(32)  NOT NULL;
ERROR 1932 (42S02): Table 'icingaweb2.icingaweb_rememberme' doesn't exist in engine
```

Icinga currently shows this error (similar to second migration error)

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'icingaweb2.icingaweb_rememberme' doesn't exist in engine
```

**Question**

How I can apply migration so that collection `icingaweb2` has table `icingaweb_rememberme`

Answer (score 0):

I found the anwser.

MySQL database created a file `icingaweb_rememberme.idb` but did not have coresponding `frm` file.

I have droped the `icingaweb_rememberme` TABLE, removed `.idb` that was left in the MySQL directory and recreated the table using single command (with second migration already applied)

This might not be the full anwser or there might be simpler solution but thats something that worked for me in this case.

**REMEMBER TO MAKE A BACKUP IF YOU ARE PLANNING ON DROPPING OR REMOVING FILES AND TABLES**